# How to add an error flow for Akka http websockets

Tags: scala, akka-stream, akka-http

I've been banging my head against the wall for quite some time as I can't figure out how to add an error flow for an akka http websocket flow. What I'm trying to achieve is:

- Message comes in from WS client
- It's parsed with circe from json
- If the message was the right format send the parsed message to an actor
- If the message was the wrong format return an error message to the client
- The actor can additionally send messages to the client

Without the error handling this was quite easy, but I can't figure out how to add the errors. Here's what I have:

```
type GameDecodeResult =
  Either[(String, io.circe.Error), GameLobby.LobbyRequest]

val errorFlow =
  Flow[GameDecodeResult]
    .mapConcat {
      case Left(err) => err :: Nil
      case Right(_) => Nil
    }
    .map { case (message, error) =>
      logger.info(s"failed to parse message $message", error)
      TextMessage(Error(error.toString).asJson.spaces2)
    }

val normalFlow = {
  val normalFlowSink =
    Flow[GameDecodeResult]
      .mapConcat {
        case Right(msg) => msg :: Nil
        case Left(_) => Nil
      }
      .map(req => GameLobby.IncomingMessage(userId, req))
      .to(Sink.actorRef[GameLobby.IncomingMessage](gameLobby, PoisonPill))

  val normalFlowSource: Source[Message, NotUsed] =
    Source.actorRef[GameLobby.OutgoingMessage](10, OverflowStrategy.fail)
      .mapMaterializedValue { outActor =>
        gameLobby ! GameLobby.UserConnected(userId, outActor)
        NotUsed
      }
      .map(outMessage => TextMessage(Ok(outMessage.message).asJson.spaces2))

  Flow.fromSinkAndSource(normalFlowSink, normalFlowSource)
}

val incomingMessageParser =
  Flow[Message]
    .flatMapConcat {
      case tm: TextMessage =>
        tm.textStream
      case bm: BinaryMessage =>
        bm.dataStream.runWith(Sink.ignore)
        Source.empty }
    .map { message =>
      decode[GameLobby.LobbyRequest](message).left.map(err => message -> err)
    }
```

These are my flows defined and I think this should bee good enough, but I have no idea how to assemble them and the complexity of the akka streaming API doesn't help. Here's what I tried:

```
val x: Flow[Message, Message, NotUsed] =
  GraphDSL.create(incomingMessageParser, normalFlow, errorFlow)((_, _, _)) { implicit builder =>
    (incoming, normal, error) =>
    import GraphDSL.Implicits._

    val partitioner = builder.add(Partition[GameDecodeResult](2, {
      case Right(_) => 0
      case Left(_) => 1
    }))

    val merge = builder.add(Merge[Message](2))

    incoming.in ~> partitioner ~> normal ~> merge
                   partitioner ~> error ~> merge
  }
```

but admittedly I have absolutely no idea how `GraphDSL.create` works, where I can use the `~>` arrow or what I'm doing in genreal at the last part. It just won't type check and the error messages are not helping me one bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things needing to be fixed in the Flow you're building using the GraphDSL:

1. There is no need to pass the 3 subflows to the `GraphDSL.create` method, as this is only needed to customize the materialized value of your graph. You have already decided the materialized value of your graph is going to be `NotUsed`.
2. When connecting `incoming` using the `~>` operator, you need to connect its outlet (`.out`) to the partition stage.
3. Every GraphDSL definition block needs to return the shape of your graph - i.e. its external ports. You do that by returning a `FlowShape` that has `incoming.in` as input, as `merge.out` as output. These will define the blueprint of your custom flow.
4. Because in the end you want to obtain a `Flow`, you're missing a last call to create is from the graph you defined. This call is `Flow.fromGraph(...)`.

Code example below:

```
  val x: Flow[Message, Message, NotUsed] =
    Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
      import GraphDSL.Implicits._

      val partitioner = builder.add(Partition[GameDecodeResult](2, {
        case Right(_) => 0
        case Left(_) => 1
      }))

      val merge = builder.add(Merge[Message](2))
      val incoming = builder.add(incomingMessageParser)

      incoming.out ~> partitioner
                      partitioner ~> normalFlow ~> merge
                      partitioner ~> errorFlow ~> merge
      FlowShape(incoming.in, merge.out)
    })
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Makes so much sense to use `incoming.out` instead of `.in`, how silly of me.